# Angular UI Grid - style the column menu/ apply a template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to use the angularjs ui-grid and have one condition: It has to be possible to style a column filter menu.

In the [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu) it is only explained how to add new items to a column menu but not how to change the design or add other controls. If we look at [the example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu) it should be possible for instance to open a column menu that can display two custom styled radio buttons (male, female) with two buttons two accept or decline the changes. If the changes are accepted, the filter should be applied.

Is it somehow possible to use templates for the column menu as it is possible for the [columns header](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/302_custom_header)? How to create a custom column menu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGYGGE9UiokINrjmrJz1?p=preview) for solution.

Within your columnDefs you just need to add menuItems. I had trouble understanding from your question what exactly you wanted these additional dropdown options to do so I've modeled the general format for you in a very simple example where the first custom option does nothing but display in your menu and the second activates an alert containing the column name. Please let me know if this is (not) sufficient.

For a full list of supported attributes for menuItems see [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu).

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    field: 'name',
    menuItems: [{
      title: 'Custom Nothing'
    }, {
      title: 'Column Name',
      action: function() {
        alert(this.context.col.displayName);
      }

    }]
  }

]
```

Comment: I *think* the OP (@timtos) was looking to add custom markup (mentions displaying radio buttons) that renders **in** the dropdown, but I'm not sure. This is actually what I'm trying to do right now.

Comment: @thynctank I concentrated on (trying to!) answer the OPs question in the final paragraph *Is it somehow possible to use templates for the column menu as it is possible for the columns header? How to create a custom column menu?*. I didn't understand what exactly the OP wanted answered in the middle paragraph so I provided a general/simple working example and hoped that if it was not sufficient for his/her needs the OP would clarify what (s)he was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Came across what I think OP was looking for, definitely what I was looking for, via http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#properties_headercellfilter

It's annoying you don't seem to be able to modify only the dropdown template, you have to override the entire header cell template, but at least you can do that on a per-col basis.